# How to parse JSON string and check if result contains the text, then ignore or allow it?

Tags: json, string, vb.net, serialization, jsonresult

I'm working on a Minecraft launcher, I have a problem, because my launcher uses the original way, and for example, here is the JSON:

```
{
  "id": "1.8.1",
  "time": "2014-11-24T14:13:31+00:00",
  "releaseTime": "2014-11-24T14:13:31+00:00",
  "type": "release",
  "minecraftArguments": "--username ${auth_player_name} --version ${version_name} --gameDir ${game_directory} --assetsDir ${assets_root} --assetIndex ${assets_index_name} --uuid ${auth_uuid} --accessToken ${auth_access_token} --userProperties ${user_properties} --userType ${user_type}",
  "minimumLauncherVersion": 14,
  "assets": "1.8",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "name": "com.ibm.icu:icu4j-core-mojang:51.2"
    },
    {
      "name": "net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.6"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:codecjorbis:20101023"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:codecwav:20101023"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:libraryjavasound:20101123"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:librarylwjglopenal:20100824"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:soundsystem:20120107"
    },
    {
      "name": "io.netty:netty-all:4.0.23.Final"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.google.guava:guava:17.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2"
    },
    {
      "name": "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
    },
    {
      "name": "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9"
    },
    {
      "name": "net.java.jinput:jinput:2.0.5"
    },
    {
      "name": "net.java.jutils:jutils:1.0.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.mojang:authlib:1.5.17"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.mojang:realms:1.7.5"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3"
    },
    {
      "name": "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.0-beta9"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.0-beta9"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl:2.9.1",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl_util:2.9.1",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:2.9.1",
      "natives": {
        "linux": "natives-linux",
        "windows": "natives-windows",
        "osx": "natives-osx"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      },
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "net.java.jinput:jinput-platform:2.0.5",
      "natives": {
        "linux": "natives-linux",
        "windows": "natives-windows",
        "osx": "natives-osx"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "tv.twitch:twitch:6.5"
    },
    {
      "name": "tv.twitch:twitch-platform:6.5",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "linux"
          }
        }
      ],
      "natives": {
        "linux": "natives-linux",
        "windows": "natives-windows-${arch}",
        "osx": "natives-osx"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "tv.twitch:twitch-external-platform:4.5",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow",
          "os": {
            "name": "windows"
          }
        }
      ],
      "natives": {
        "windows": "natives-windows-${arch}"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "mainClass": "net.minecraft.client.main.Main"
}
```

So, in the `"libraries" [`, the game libraries listed with `"name":`, and below, the libraries contains the rules that apply to them, I want to know this rules with the library file name, and apply the actions with it, but I don't have any idea, I using this code, but this only redirect the libraries.

Here is my code:

```
 Dim item As String = Version
        Dim client As New WebClient()
        Await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(New Uri("https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/" + item + "/" + item + ".json"), Root + "\versions\" + item + "\" + item + ".json")
        Dim JSONREADER As New StreamReader(Root + "\versions\" + item + "\" + item + ".json")
        json = JSONREADER.ReadToEnd()
        JSONREADER.Close()
        Dim JSONResult As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(json)
        MinecraftArgs = JSONResult("minecraftArguments")
        AssetIndex = JSONResult("assets")
        MainClass = JSONResult("mainClass")
        For Each i In JSONResult("libraries").Children()
            LibrariesList.Add(i.ToObject(Of MClibraries).name)
        Next
```

For example:

```
{
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl:2.9.1",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
```

The "name" as the name of the file, the "rules" there is two action: allow, disallow, under the disallow, there is the "os":, this sets the action, because

```
"os": {
                "name": "osx"
              }
```

this only allows the file in Windows and Linux, but disallows the file in mac OS X, so I want to get and apply this actions.

I want to add these libraries:

```
"libraries": [
    {
      "name": "com.ibm.icu:icu4j-core-mojang:51.2"
    },
    {
      "name": "net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.6"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:codecjorbis:20101023"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:codecwav:20101023"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:libraryjavasound:20101123"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:librarylwjglopenal:20100824"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.paulscode:soundsystem:20120107"
    },
    {
      "name": "io.netty:netty-all:4.0.23.Final"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.google.guava:guava:17.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2"
    },
    {
      "name": "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
    },
    {
      "name": "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9"
    },
    {
      "name": "net.java.jinput:jinput:2.0.5"
    },
    {
      "name": "net.java.jutils:jutils:1.0.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.mojang:authlib:1.5.17"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.mojang:realms:1.7.5"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3"
    },
    {
      "name": "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.0-beta9"
    },
    {
      "name": "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.0-beta9"
    },
```

And add these libraries if the rules allow Windows operating system:

```
{
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl:2.9.1",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl_util:2.9.1",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:2.9.1",
      "natives": {
        "linux": "natives-linux",
        "windows": "natives-windows",
        "osx": "natives-osx"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      },
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "osx"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "net.java.jinput:jinput-platform:2.0.5",
      "natives": {
        "linux": "natives-linux",
        "windows": "natives-windows",
        "osx": "natives-osx"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "tv.twitch:twitch:6.5"
    },
    {
      "name": "tv.twitch:twitch-platform:6.5",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow"
        },
        {
          "action": "disallow",
          "os": {
            "name": "linux"
          }
        }
      ],
      "natives": {
        "linux": "natives-linux",
        "windows": "natives-windows-${arch}",
        "osx": "natives-osx"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "tv.twitch:twitch-external-platform:4.5",
      "rules": [
        {
          "action": "allow",
          "os": {
            "name": "windows"
          }
        }
      ],
      "natives": {
        "windows": "natives-windows-${arch}"
      },
      "extract": {
        "exclude": [
          "META-INF/"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
```

If in the rules only disallow, and in the disallow only for example OS X, this means the Windows, and the Linux allowed.

Comment: Totally irrelevant, but you're going about concatenating your url all wrong. You should use this instead `Await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(New Uri(String.Format("https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/{0}/{0}.json", item)), String.Format("{0}\versions\{1}\{1}.json", Root, item))` because it is much more easier to read

Comment: Something you could add to this topic as well is your MClibraries class so we can further help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First edit your MClibraries class so that it looks like this:

```
Public Class MClibraries
    Public name As String
    Public rules As JArray
End Class
```

So to do what you're asking I start off with a list and a dictionary:

```
Private ReadOnly _librariesList As New List(Of String)
Private ReadOnly _disallowed As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

NOTE: You already have _librariesList, but yours is named LibrariesList.

Next, to get the libraries, I did this:

```
Dim item As String = Version
Dim client = New WebClient() With {.Proxy = Nothing}
Dim json = Await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(New Uri(String.Format("http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/{0}/{0}.json", item)))
Dim jsonResult As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(json)
For Each i In jsonResult("libraries")
    Dim entry As MClibraries = i.ToObject(Of MClibraries)() ' Converts object to MClibrary
    _librariesList.Add(entry.name) ' Add the name of each entry to the listbox
    If Not IsNothing(entry.rules) AndAlso entry.rules.Count = 2 Then ' Check to make sure it isn't empty
        _disallowed.Add(entry.rules(1)("os")("name")) ' Gets the os that is disallowed
    End If
Next
```

NOTE: Just add what you already have to this

Now you can access all the disallowed os's with the new dictionary "_disallowed". The key is the os that is disallowed and the value is the package.

If you want to see if the os matches the user os you can write the following. Also you will need to add the reference to System.Management and import it as well

```
Private _currentOs as String 

'The following should go under the loading of a form
Dim osname As String = (From x In New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().OfType(Of ManagementObject)()
            Select x.GetPropertyValue("Caption")).FirstOrDefault()

'The following should go where you retrieve the libraries
For Each i In jsonResult("libraries")
    Dim entry As MClibraries = i.ToObject(Of MClibraries)() ' Converts object to MClibrary
    If Not IsNothing(entry.rules) AndAlso entry.rules.Count = 2 Then ' Check to make sure it isn't empty
        If Not _currentOs.ToLower.Contains(entry.rules(1)("os")("name")) Then
            _librariesList.Add(entry.name)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dom Stepek!

Comment: Dom Stepek, I have one last question, Can I add the allowed libraries into the list with your code automatically? Thanks

Comment: If you want the allowed instead of disallowed try changing the `_disallowed.Add(entry.rules(1)("os")("name"))` to `_disallowed.Add(entry.rules(0)("os")("name"))`. It may work, I'll check to see if there's a better way

Comment: I want to add allowed libraries to the list, can you write this? Thanks! :)

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Can you give an example

Comment: As for that error, all you have to do is change the underlined line to `_disallowed.Add(entry.rules(0)("os")("name"), entry.name)`. As for checking whether or not the end-user has the 'allowed' os, there isn't much point considering that unless you're using Mono, the end-user will always use Windows @Programmer2011

Comment: for what I want, example in the question.

Comment: Since I am not sure what you're asking, I'll give you the information that I think you are asking for. Look at the new edited post @Programmer2011